# Apache ignite ARRAY_AGG equivalent

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, ignite

Is there an aggregation function for Apache Ignite similar to ARRAY_AGG? I'm trying to pass multiple values to a custom function after grouping, but I was not able to do it for Apache Ignite query ( same query in posgresql was done with ARRAY_AGG and Group by)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GROUP_CONTACT](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/aggregate-functions#group_concat)

Also check out [custom sql functions](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/custom-sql-func). These might help your use case.

Comment: I'm not sure why I can't pass multiple values to GROUP_CONCAT / custom SQL function. If I have 3 rows, I group by row 1 and 2 it will say I need to group by row 3 as well if I want to pass value of row3 to the function. If I group by row 3 , I will pass just 1 value, instead of all values for row 2